# Full UK license visiting US: Can I use frequencies in US but not UK license?

Tags: united-states, license, united-kingdom, international-operating

E.g.:

- 7.2-7.3MHz are Region 2 but not Region 1. My license is "from" Region 1.
- 1.25 meter band is not available in the UK
- Operating from aircraft is not permitted in the UK. Would it be if I visited the US?

I realise that any frequencies not allowed in Region 2 would of course be a no-no when transmitting inside Region 2.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're correct in your understanding about region: given that you're operating in a part of the US that is in Region 2 (there are a few US overseas territories in Region 3), you need to conform to the Region 2 band plan, and not any other.

FCC regulation 97.301(b), concerning authorized frequencies, grants the same privileges to a CEPT (non-novice) license-holder as to the holder of an Amateur Extra license (the highest class of license in the US). Since you will be in the United States, this is the only thing that governs what you are and aren't allowed to do, not your privileges in your home country. Your UK full license meets the criteria, so you have all of the privileges of an Extra while operating in the US, in terms of frequencies, aerial operation, and whatever else.

Answer (score 6):

As a UK license holder operating in the United States, you will be operating under CEPT Recommendation T/R 61-01.

According to the [CEPT regulations](https://www.ecodocdb.dk/download/2ae38a89-e58a/TR6101.pdf)(PDF), it explicitly states that:

> The CEPT Licence permits utilisation of all frequency bands allocated to the Amateur Service and Amateur Satellite Service and authorised in the country where the amateur station is to be operated.

With a note that:

> Special attention should be paid to the difference in frequency allocations to the radio amateur services in the three ITU Regions

According to their [FAQ document](https://www.cept.org/files/12338/FAQ%20Radio%20Amateur%20Updated%208%20February%202017.docx)(MS Word document), this is also the case:

> **Whose operating privileges should the visitor use?**
>
> The operating privileges for the visitor operating under the CEPT Licence are defined by the COUNTRY BEING VISITED, NOT THE PRIVILEGES IN HIS *[sic]* OWN COUNTRY.

So you have full access to all the US bands, regardless of where you are from. Just make sure to operate according to the US regulations at all times.

(Source for this information: the [Operating Abroad](http://rsgb.org/main/operating/licensing-novs-visitors/operating-abroad/) page on the RSGB website.)